# movie schedule algorithm in algorithm design manual book

Tags: algorithm

I have a question regarding the correct answer for movie schedule algorithm.

Problem: Movie Scheduling Problem

Input: A set I of n intervals on the line.

Output: What is the largest subset of mutually non-overlapping intervals which can be selected from I?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf4bz.png)

The correct answer in the book is:

While total jobs I != 0:

Accept the job j from total jobs I with the earliest completion date. Delete j, and any interval which intersects j from I.

I am thinking about the following scenario:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSlPY.png)

in this case, job1 ends first, but isn't job2 the best job to choose?

Thanks, I am just starting to learn algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object is to maximize the total number of jobs chosen so when you only take job1 or only take job2 the solution is one job only in both cases.

The choice of the job which has the earliest completion date means that you can find the maximum number of non overlapping jobs as if you choose a job which finishes later it won't gives you a better answer because there maybe a job that starts in the time between the finish of job1 and the finish of job2 if you choose job2 you won't be able to add that job

Comment: Thanks! So do you mean in this question, the object is to maximize the total number of jobs chosen, not total hours worked? I thought the actor's pay is determined by total hours worked, so the object is to find the jobs combination that maximize working hours.

Comment: @ZheDang the output here is the largest subset which means the one that contains the most movies which is why this solution works if you want to maximize the total work time it's a completely different problem and won't work using the above algorithm